# Calculating the limit of a sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

In one of the exercises I got, I was required in order to proceed to calculate the limit:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac 1 {e^n} (1+ \frac 1 n)^{n^2})$

I checked in the solution sheet to see if the answer will give me a clue, and the answer is supposed to be $\frac 1 {\sqrt e}$ but I still can't see how I get there...
Can anyone please give me a clue? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac 1 {e^x} (1+ \frac 1 x)^{x^2}=\left(\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x}{e}\right)^x=e^{x\left(ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x-lne\right)}=e^{\frac{ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x-1}{\frac{1}{x}}}$

Now apply L'Hôpital's rule twice on the exponent and you will get the result.

Comment: Now that solved it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If
$a_n
= \frac 1 {e^n} (1+ \frac 1 n)^{n^2}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
\ln a_n
&=n^2\ln (1+ \frac 1 n)-n\\
&=n^2(\frac1{n}-\frac1{2n^2}+O(\frac1{n^3}))-n\\
&=(n-\frac12+O(\frac1{n}))-n\\
&=-\frac12+O(\frac1{n})\\
&\to -\frac12\\
\end{array}
$

so
$a_n \to e^{-1/2}$.